# preventing specific ajax accordion pane from expanding until some condition happened

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have an ajax accordion consists of 3 panes and I need to prevent the last 2 panes from expanding except if controls in first pane was filled correctly.

Any suggestions on what event can I use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script prevents users from expanding Pane 3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {
        RemoveHandlerAtRuntime(2);          
    }


    function RemoveHandlerAtRuntime(pane)
    {
         $removeHandler($find('AccordionCtrl_AccordionExtender').get_Pane(pane).header,"click",$find('AccordionCtrl_AccordionExtender')._headerClickHandler);
    }

</script>
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=215